# Tracking cells and corresponding related data in excel

Tags: excel, vba

Really struggling to describe my problem with the title so please bear with me!

I have a spreadsheet that is displaying the pdf files within a directory as hyperlinks using the following forumula in column B: -

```
=IFERROR(HYPERLINK(LEFT($Y$6,LEN($Y$6)-4)&INDEX(checking,ROW()-ROW(B$7)),INDEX(checking,ROW()-ROW(B$7))),"")
```

Edit:The hyperlink formula is repeated in every row (down to around 150) in column B, as pdfs are added to the directory the formula populates the cell with its filename. The order that the pdfs display in appears to be as windows orders it.

The directory location is defined in cell Y6 and that works fine.  In column C I have a drop down list of comments that are used to control conditional formatting.  I am trying to get the comment cell to track the row of the pdf hyperlink cell; as new pdf files are added to the directory the comments rows get disordered.

My attempt is to trawl through the column containing the pdf hyperlinks, copy the pdf filename and it's associated comment cells that I want to track using the following code: -

```
Sub save_status()
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim sheet As String

sheet = ActiveSheet.Name
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("Y35").Value

Worksheets(sheet).Activate

Range("AA:AM").ClearContents

    For i = 8 To lastrow

        If Range("B" & i).Value <> "" And Range("C" & i).Value = "" Then
            ActiveSheet.Range("C" & i).Value = "Pending"
        End If

        If Range("B" & i).Value <> "" Then
            ActiveSheet.Range("AB" & i).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i)
            ActiveSheet.Range("AC" & i).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & i)
            ActiveSheet.Range("AH" & i).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("H" & i)
            ActiveSheet.Range("AN" & i).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("N" & i)
        End If

        If Range("D" & i).Value <> "" Then
            ActiveSheet.Range("AD" & i).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("D" & i)
            ActiveSheet.Range("AE" & i).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("E" & i)
            ActiveSheet.Range("AI" & i).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("I" & i)
            ActiveSheet.Range("AO" & i).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("O" & i)
        End If

        If Range("F" & i).Value <> "" Then
            ActiveSheet.Range("AF" & i).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("F" & i)
            ActiveSheet.Range("AG" & i).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("G" & i)
        End If

        If Range("N" & i).Value = "Checked" Then
            ActiveSheet.Range("AB" & i).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i)
            ActiveSheet.Range("AN" & i).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("N" & i)
        End If

    Next i

    Range("B6").Select

    End Sub
```

This copies the data out to cells elsewhere on the sheet.  I then clear the original comments cells and restore the data back on a row by row basis using a find and offsetting values as per: -

```
Sub restore_status()
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim sheet As String
Dim filename As String
Dim status As String
Dim comment As String
Dim check As String
Dim found As Range

sheet = ActiveSheet.Name
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("Y35").Value

Worksheets(sheet).Activate


Range("H8:I500").ClearContents
Range("N8:N500").ClearContents

For i = 8 To lastrow

        Range("C" & i).ClearContents
           If Range("AB" & i).Value <> "" Then
                filename = ActiveSheet.Range("AB" & i)
                status = ActiveSheet.Range("AC" & i)
                comment = ActiveSheet.Range("AH" & i)
                Set found = Range("B8:B" & lastrow).find(filename, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)
                found.Offset(0, 1).Value = status
                found.Offset(0, 6).Value = comment
            End If

        Range("E" & i).ClearContents
           If Range("AD" & i).Value <> "" Then
                filename = ActiveSheet.Range("AD" & i)
                status = ActiveSheet.Range("AE" & i)
                check = ActiveSheet.Range("AO" & i)
                Set found = Range("D8:D" & lastrow).find(filename, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)
                found.Offset(0, 1).Value = status
                found.Offset(0, 5).Value = comment
                found.Offset(0, 11).Value = check

            End If

        Range("G" & i).ClearContents
           If Range("AF" & i).Value <> "" Then
                filename = ActiveSheet.Range("AF" & i)
                status = ActiveSheet.Range("AG" & i)
                Set found = Range("F8:F" & lastrow).find(filename, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)
                found.Offset(0, 1).Value = status
            End If

        Range("N" & i).ClearContents
           If Range("AN" & i).Value = "Checked" Then
                filename = ActiveSheet.Range("AB" & i)
                status = ActiveSheet.Range("AN" & i)
                Set found = Range("B8:B" & lastrow).find(filename, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)
                found.Offset(0, 12).Value = status
            End If

Next i

Call Hide_checking_if_checked

Call Hide_checking_if_approved

Worksheets(sheet).Activate
Range("AA:AN").ClearContents

End Sub
```

This falls over if a new pdf is dropped into the folder, it seems to stop the find rountine as soon as it hits the new file.  In my understanding of it, the code should trawl through the filenames stored in column AB, find the matching name in column B and write the offset data in and then moving on to the next filename in AB.

Apologies for the somewhat long post and possibly convoluted coding, still very new so learning all the time!

Any pointers as to where have I gone wrong?

edit:

[Here's a slightly simplified workflow of the bit that's failing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXgNM.png)

[Here's the list of drawings before triggering the refresh macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5bXY.png)

[Here's the list of drawing after triggering the refresh macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GEMZ.png)

Between the before and after triggering images, drawing 014-Rev.C1 was added to the folder, this naturally ordered itself after 014-Rev.C0 which makes sense.

What you can see is that it's not copied any of the Status data in column C after the new file number is encountered in B:B; 014-Rev.C1 doesn't exist in the saved data in columns AB and AC.

What I think it should do is skip past the 014-Rev.C1 and copy the status data offset against 015-Rev.C0 and so on so forth.

For reference the "Checked" status in column C is inserted by a different macro that works inversely to how this is supposed to work, it trawls the D:D column, stores the drawing number, finds the stored number in B:B and writes the value "Checked" into the cell.

The code doesn't give an error at all, just doesn't copy all of the data.

Comment: "stop the find rountine" - do you mean the filename is not found? Your code should allow for that possibility to avoid errors.

Comment: If a file is deleted from the directory then it gives an error in the code, I would expect that but it shouldn't be something that happens as the files should only be being added; as such it's not something that I'm concentrating on specifically but something I can look into for future development.

I don't think I've explained the failure well enough: -

Column B originally has 5 entries and 5 comments, a new pdf is added to the directory and now there are 6 entries and 5 comments, typically the new file will be in the middle of the existing files so not tacked onto the end.

Comment: How is `lastrow` updated?

Comment: It's defined by a cell that counts the number of rows containing data, not sure on the actual formula offhand but it works well.

Comment: It's not very clear from your description what your actual workflow is - you mention new files being added, but not how that happens, or really why you're doing what you're doing: there should be no need to copy/recopy the values when adding or deleting rows from your table.

Comment: So is the problem that `found.Offset(0, 1).Value = status` errors? If so it's not finding the name. Btw better to use sheet names rather than activesheet.

Comment: The pdfs are dropped into the directory using a robocopy script, this spreadsheet then allows users to see the status of the files (specifically these are engineering drawings transitioning through various stages of approval). As a new file is issued for approval it's automatically dropped into the directory. I'm not adding or deleting rows from the table, but as the pdfs are added the row that they're displayed changes. I want the comments cell to track the row as and when it changes if that makes sense.

Comment: The code doesn't error, it just doesn't behave as I believe it should. In the restore sub, once I have stored the filename I then want to store the other data as necessary and then find the stored filename in column B and paste the stored data into the relative cells using the offsets. I'm really bad at explaining this but I have a perfectly clear image in my head of what it's meant to do!

Comment: @SJR - about the using sheet names, presume you mean replace the activesheet with the stored sheet name within the for loop?

Comment: Yes specify sheet names. A simplified picture might help to explain.

Comment: I'll try to produce a simple workflow diagram for the morning, a picture paints a thousand words etc etc!

Comment: Seems like the point to address is wherever you're getting the list of filenames from the folder - as you get each filename, you can either match it to an existing row, or add a new row.

Comment: The list of filenames is coming directly from the folder, there are no new rows added.  I want the status and comment cells to match with the drawing number that they were originally matched to.  I'll try to get some images sorted out.

Comment: I have edited the post to include workflow and screencaps with a little more information on the process it's going through.